# What is the purpose of exports "./package.json" in package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I see some npm modules' package.json has such `exports`

```
{
  "name": "my-package",
  "exports": {
    ".": "./lib/index.js",
    "./package.json": "./package.json"
  }
}
```

What is the purpose of `"./package.json": "./package.json"` in **exports**? I searched the npm document for [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json) but that does not mention `exports`.

Answer (score 1):

Although npm document doesn't provide an explanation of the `exports` keyword I find nodejs document explains it.

From [nodejs 14.x](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/packages.html#packages_package_entry_points),

> The "exports" field provides an alternative to "main" where the
> package main entry point can be defined while also encapsulating the
> package, preventing any other entry points besides those defined in
> "exports". This encapsulation allows module authors to define a public
> interface for their package.
>
> Warning: Introducing the "exports" field prevents consumers of a
> package from using any entry points that are not defined, including
> the package.json (e.g. require('your-package/package.json'). This will
> likely be a breaking change.

And I find it is an evolving feature. At [nodejs 12.x it added](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/packages.html#packages_main_entry_point_export)

> To set the main entry point for a package, it is advisable to define
> both "exports" and "main" in the package’s package.json file:
>
> ```
> {
>   "main": "./main.js",
>   "exports": "./main.js"
> }
> ```
>
> When the "exports" field is defined, all subpaths of the package are
> encapsulated and no longer available to importers. For example,
> require('pkg/subpath.js') throws an ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED
> error.
>
> It is not a strong encapsulation since a direct require of any absolute subpath of the package such as require('/path/to/node_modules/pkg/subpath.js') will still load subpath.js.

At [nodejs 14.x it added Subpath exports](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/packages.html#packages_subpath_exports)

> ```
> {
>   "main": "./main.js",
>   "exports": {
>     ".": "./main.js",
>     "./submodule": "./src/submodule.js"
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Now only the defined subpath in "exports" can be imported by a
> consumer, While other subpaths will error.